# Is this wall load-bearing (Blue prints included)?

Tags: load-bearing, remodeling

We just bought a house and would like to remove a partial wall that was added as part of a remodel. I have the blueprints for the remodel (completed with permits in the 80s).  I've attached images of the relevant portions.  The house is in San Diego, CA, if that makes any difference.

The wall I'd like to remove is circled in red and the location of the original exterior wall is highlighted in blue.  I've also attached the plans for the changes to the foundation.

I'm new to reading blueprints, but it looks like there's a 4x14 beam running across a post at the end of the wall we'd like to remove, and that post is firmly attached to the foundation.  This makes me think that we can remove the wall but not the post.

Does that seem correct?

I'm also curious about what "CC' CAP" and "2x8 PERIN" annotations mean.

[image: Blueprints showing the wall I'd like removed and the original exterior wall of house.]

[image: Blueprints for the foundation.]

Comment: I would assume that the faint lines are joists above but I have assumed that before and have been proven wrong.    Also is the solid blue line a wall?   I know it was the exterior wall but is it a wall now?    Do you have the upper floor blueprints?   I would guess it isn't load bearing but the fact that the corner intersects and the fact that it sits on a joists...  I don't think you can make a call just from the blueprints you showed.

Comment: The blue line is the former location of the exterior wall. It is no longer there.

Comment: And the red wall was added during the expansion of the exterior wall?

Comment: yes, that's correct.

Comment: If there is a joist running from left to right (closer to the bottom of the red wall) that really muddies things.   Also is that a bathroom with the zig zag wall?    I am confused why there is a joist running left to right and why it only intersects with two walls.   If it is deflecting some of the load, just assuming it can get by with one attached section... I wouldn't make that assumption.

Answer (score 1):

### Wall Questions

> This makes me think that we can remove the wall but not the post. Does that seem correct?

**Wall:**

The wall is not load bearing as it is parallel to the roof rafters which bear on the exterior and interior perpendicular walls

HOWEVER it may be part of the lateral system which resists horizontal from wind and earthquakes

**Post**

It must remain as it is the support for the two 4x14 beams

### Annotations Questions

> "CC' CAP"

Column or post cap. This is a prefabricated post and beam connection. The specific type will be shown in another place on your plan, likely either the plan notes, or the general notes

> "2x8 PERIN"

A type of roof brace. Refer the picture below

[image]